# How to get frame coordinates of a UIView within a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I simply want to get the frame coordinates of a UIView iVar contained within a UIViewController.  For example, if but0 is the iVar, and this fcn is called from the ViewController ViewDidLoad method:

```
CGFloat x = self.but0.frame.origin.x;
```

This always returns 0, no matter where the button is placed with Interface Builder.  What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure your `but0` outlet is hooked up to the button in Interface Builder?

Comment: Try it in the `viewDidAppear` method of the UIViewController.

Comment: yes, i'm sure 'but0' is hooked up in IB. I also tried to make the call in 'viewDidAppear' and 'viewWillAppear'.  'viewDidAppear' worked!  but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewDidLoad loads the view but the frame/bounds have not been set.
ViewDidAppear is guaranteed to happen after the frame/bounds have been set. Use that method.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Spectravideo328 is right, you should use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

You could try to convert the frame of the  from the UIView.
Something like:

`CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:btn.frame fromView:tableView.frame];`

Comment: my original call in, but made in 'viewDidAppear' did solve this issue.  So why did that work?